# GTK 3 How to connect one signal to multiple widgets?

Tags: c++, forms, signals, gtk3

I need to create a form with the model created by the code bellow, composed by a window with two text entries and one button.

I need to put some text in the entries, and when the button is pressed, put the text gotten in the two entries in an array, (or print them both, or any action with both at the same time)

The code used to create the window is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
using namespace std;

GtkWidget *wventana;
GtkWidget *wgrid;

void ventana(string titulo, int margen)
{
    const char * tituloc = titulo.c_str();
    wventana = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
}

void grid()
{
    wgrid = gtk_grid_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(wventana), wgrid);
}

void boton(string texto, int x, int y, int lx, int ly)
{
    const char * wtexto = texto.c_str();

    GtkWidget *wboton;
    wboton = gtk_button_new_with_label (wtexto);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (wgrid), wboton, x, y, lx, ly);
}

void entrada(int x, int y, int lx, int ly)
{
    GtkWidget *wentrada;
    wentrada = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (wgrid), wentrada, x, y, lx, ly);
}

//INICIO
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    ventana("ventana",10);
    grid();
    entrada(2, 1, 1, 1);
    entrada(2, 2, 1, 1);
    boton("Procesar", 2, 3, 1, 1);

    gtk_widget_show_all (wventana);
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Please, could someone clarify how can this be made (is not necessary to use the code provided, its only for reference on the results needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a structure that you pass as `user_data` to your signal handlers:

```
typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *entrada1, *entrada2;
} Widgets;

...

// in main():
Widgets *w = g_slice_new0 (Widgets);
w->entrada1 = entrada (2, 1, 1, 1); // remember to return the widget from entrada()!
w->entrada2 = entrada (2, 2, 1, 1);
GtkWidget *procesar = boton ("Procesar", 2, 3, 1, 1);
g_signal_connect(procesar, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (on_procesar), w);
// ...
gtk_main ();
g_slice_free (Widgets, w);

...

void
on_procesar (GtkButton *procesar, Widgets *w)
{
    // do something with w->entrada1 and w->entrada2
}
```

Comment: Thanks again ptomato. I tried to apply the changes you suggested, but, since I'm a newbie, I don't how to return the widget from entrada(). Can you explain me how to do it please?                  

By the way I tried to vote you up, but I dont have enough reputation. But thanks .

Comment: Use `return wentrada;` at the end of the function, and make sure to change the return type of `entrada()` from `void` to `GtkWidget *`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that, and that part doesnt cause any more poblems... but the line `GtkWidget *procesar = boton ("Procesar", 2, 3, 1, 1);` throws the error: `void value not ignored as it ought to be`.
why does this happen? PD: you seem to know a lot about GTK, do you know about a guide I can follow to learn it, please?

Comment: Also make sure to change the return type of `boton()` to `GtkWidget *` instead of `void`. I can recommend the tutorials on developer.gnome.org, but since you are struggling with return types I would also recommend a guide to C - my personal favorite is _The C Programming Language_ by Kernighan and Ritchie, but there are many out there.

Comment: Hello, I have a new problem with the same code. Inside on_procesar() I wrote `const char * texto = gtk_entry_get_text(entrada1));
 cout << texto << endl;` but it says `entrada1` is not defined in the scope. and I tried `const char * texto = gtk_entry_get_text(w->entrada1));
 cout << texto << endl;` and i get `cannot convert ‘GtkWidget* {aka _GtkWidget*}’ to ‘GtkEntry* {aka _GtkEntry*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘const gchar* gtk_entry_get_text(GtkEntry*)’`So now I have no idea on how to get the text from the entry. Please help me with this last one. (Thanks for all your patience, really)

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question. Otherwise other people won't be able to find it when they need help with the same problem.