# GTK 3 How to connect one signal to multiple widgets? (part 2)

Tags: c++, forms, signals, gtk3

This is the continuation of this question: [GTK 3 How to connect one signal to multiple widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799350/gtk-3-how-to-connect-one-signal-to-multiple-widgets/25800619?noredirect=1#comment40587641_25800619)

I have some code in C++ using GTK3.

It creates two text entries and one button. I want an action to be done with the text entered when the button is pressed. (In this case I just want the text to be printed.) The code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
using namespace std;

GtkWidget *wventana;
GtkWidget *wgrid;

typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *entrada1, *entrada2;
} Widgets;

void on_procesar (GtkButton *procesar, Widgets *w)
{
    const char * texto = gtk_entry_get_text(entrada1);
    cout << texto << endl;
}

void ventana(string titulo, int margen)
{
    const char * tituloc = titulo.c_str();

    wventana = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
}

void grid()
{
    wgrid = gtk_grid_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(wventana), wgrid);
}

GtkWidget *boton(string texto, int x, int y, int lx, int ly)
{
    const char * wtexto = texto.c_str();

    GtkWidget *wboton;
    wboton = gtk_button_new_with_label (wtexto);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (wgrid), wboton, x, y, lx, ly);
    return wboton;
}

GtkWidget *entrada(int x, int y, int lx, int ly)
{
    GtkWidget *wentrada;
    wentrada = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (wgrid), wentrada, x, y, lx, ly);
    return wentrada;
}

//INICIO
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    ventana("ventana",10);
    grid();

    Widgets *w = g_slice_new (Widgets);
    w->entrada1 = entrada (2, 1, 1, 1);
    w->entrada2 = entrada (2, 2, 1, 1);
    GtkWidget * procesar = boton ("Procesar", 2, 3, 1, 1);
    g_signal_connect(procesar, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (on_procesar), w);

    gtk_widget_show_all (wventana);
    gtk_main ();
    g_slice_free (Widgets, w);

    return 0;
}
```

Right now my problem is in on_procesar() where I dont know how to get the text from the entries, because I don't know how to indicate the entry widget I want to use. (its not defined in the scope).

Please can anyone explain me how can this be done?

Comment: @ptomato I made the question again so everyone can find it. I really hope you can help me this time. Also, thanks for all your previous answers.

Comment: The whole point of stack overflow is that it doesn't have to be me who helps you but anyone who encounters your question first. For example, if I haven't commented on this question yet, then @mentioning me does nothing ;-)

Comment: ohh, I didnt know about the mentioning thing :D ... but I did it because you already helped me with this code before, and you seem to know the topic very well, but I'm definitely open to diferent people answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `w->entrada1` in your `on_procesar()` handler instead of `entrada1`. The point of the structure `w` is to keep track of all the widgets that you want to use in your various signal handlers, so that you can keep them in scope by passing `w` as the user data to each handler.

Comment: I did that, but i got  `cannot convert ‘GtkWidget* {aka _GtkWidget*}’ to ‘GtkEntry* {aka _GtkEntry*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘const gchar* gtk_entry_get_text(GtkEntry*)’`, so I searched and I found a solution, i replaced `w->entrada1` with `GTK_ENTRY (w->entrada1)`, and it worked as I spected (at last!). I guess the problem is now solved, thanks again.